# TaskJuggler does not antedate task with fix end date and produces error

Tags: task, project, schedule

I'm starting with TaskJuggler with very little programming experience.

From my point of view TaskJuggler does not "juggle" tasks to avoid overstaying end dates. I can't imagine, that TaskJuggler ist not able to shift such tasks. However I do not find the corresponding failure in my script.

Here is a minimal example. Taskjuggler places wp1a before wp1b and produces an error. Forcing wp1b before wp1a by `priority` is no problem. But with the option `end` it is not working:

```
project work "Work"  2021-11-01-00:00 +3m {

  scenario plan "Plan" {
  }
}

rate 200.0

account cost "Project Cost"
account rev "Payments"
balance cost rev

resource me "Me" {
  email "me@univer.se"
  rate 100
}

task wp1 "Task" {
  task wp1a "Subtask 1" {
    effort 1m
    allocate me
  }
  task wp1b "Subtask 2" {
    effort 2d
    allocate me
    end 2021-11-19
  }
}

navigator navbar {
  hidereport @none
}

macro TaskTip [
  tooltip istask() -8<-
    '''Start: ''' <-query attribute='start'->
    '''End: ''' <-query attribute='end'->
    ----
    '''Resources:'''

    <-query attribute='resources'->
    ----
    '''Precursors: '''

    <-query attribute='precursors'->
    ----
    '''Followers: '''

    <-query attribute='followers'->
    ->8-
]

textreport frame "" {
  header -8<-
    == Accounting Software Project ==
    <[navigator id="navbar"]>
  ->8-
  footer "----"
  textreport index "Overview" {
    formats html
    center '<[report id="overview"]>'
  }
}

taskreport overview "" {
  header -8<-
    === Original Project Plan ===
  ->8-
  columns bsi { title 'WBS' },
          name, start, end, effort, cost,
          revenue, chart { ${TaskTip} }
  timeformat "%a %Y-%m-%d"
  loadunit days
  hideresource @all
  balance cost rev
  caption 'All effort values are in man days.'
}
```

After some warnings considering the not scheduled task the error

> Some tasks did not fit into the project time frame.

appears.

Comment: Further information: Tested versions: 3.3.0 and 3.7.1; Taskjuggler sorts the tasks by descending effort; according to manual `end` should be recognized by scheduler - contrary to `maxend`. Taskjuggler does not schedule satisfying as well, using a depending milestone with definite date.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how Taskjuggler attempts to schedule tasks.
Taskjuggler will attempt to schedule the two tasks in descending order since both tasks have the same priority.

So T1 is scheduled first from 2021-11-01 until 2021-12-01, then T2 is scheduled but its end date 2021-11-19 has allready passed and can not be scheduled, hence Taskjuggler raises the error.